# Understanding MPU6050 readings

Tags: accelerometer

This forum has been extremely helpful so far for me working on my project so I thank this great community!

I am currently using an MPU6050 6 axis accelerometer and gyroscope with my arduino, but I am having trouble understanding the values.
I am using the "basicreadings" program from https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-mpu-6050-accelerometer-gyroscope-arduino/. However this issue has occured with all the programs I use.

The accelerometer values that are returned do not appear to be acceleration at all but an angle, because when I move the MPU6050 to a different location and hold it, the accelerometer values change but then do not go back to their original value but instead remain at a new value. Surely once it stops moving it should return to it's default 0 value wheverver the MPU6050 is in space? Therefore what is the accelerometer actually measuring? If anyone has any experience with the MPU6050 I would be really grateful for any info you can offer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Acceleration includes gravity! When the device is rotating but otherwise staying in place, the acceleration you get as a result will point in the direction of gravity, which will appear exactly like a direction vector and thus indirectly measure angle.

Comment: Hey thaks for the reply! But I don't follow. I am not rotating the device. Say I just move it to another location in the x direction and then hold it there. I would expect the x component of the accelerometer to change and then return to 0. But it does not, it stays at a new value. That has me wondering if the value I am getting is not acceleration?

Comment: That sounds like it could be an accumulated acceleration, which is useful if you cannot get data from the device at a consistent rate. I don't see anything in the datasheet to suggest this is a mode of operation provided. Is your software automatically doing this? Which register are you reading?

Comment: I am not sure but my software is automatically doing it. I am just using the basicreadings program linked at the start in arduino